# JavaScript & PHP checkbox select all

Tags: php, javascript, html, checkbox

I have problem with select checkbox with the JavaScript in the HTML file. I know how to do this but in my form all checkbox have `name='chk[]'`:

```
<form name="forms" action='index.php' method='post'>
    <input type='checkbox' name='chk[]' value='value1'> ANY VALUE 1 </br>
    <input type='checkbox' name='chk[]' value='value2'> ANY VALUE 2 </br>
    <input type='checkbox' name='chk[]' value='value3'> ANY VALUE 3 </br>
    <input type='checkbox' name='chk[]' value='value4'> ANY VALUE 4 </br>
    <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Get Value'>
</form>
```

In my PHP file I use select checkbox:

```
<?php
    $s = "";
    $value = $_POST['chk'];

    $s .= join(", ", $value);

    echo $s;
```

But how can I create a function in JavaScript which checks the field.
I've also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7259335/select-all-checkbox)

Comment: Can you post the HTML that contains the checkboxes?

Comment: Include the HTML for the checkboxes that is generated by your PHP code in the question, as well as the Javascript code you've tried that doesn't work, please.

Comment: So you want a script that checks all the checkboxes?  Would it make sense to do this when the form is rendered, or is this a convenience button for the user to one-click and check all the boxes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check all checkboxes dynamically, you can use the follwing code:

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++)
    if(inputs[i].type == "checkbox")
        inputs[i].checked = true;
```

To check a checkbox by default, just add `checked='checked'` to the tag:

```
<input type='checkbox' name='chk[]' value='value' checked='checked'>
```

Comment: Replace `'checked'` with `true`. You are accessing the boolean property, not the string attribute.

Comment: Ok thx it's work fine now. I must create dynamic check, uncheck checbox in site generate by php. I don't know hove much was checkbox, and I need take it value.