# Check all checkbox with an array

Tags: php, javascript, checkbox

Trying to make the infamous checkall checkbox for dynamically created rows from a MySQL query. Rows (and therefore checkboxes) could range from 1 row to a metric buttload.

The form (without the checkall) is as follows:

```
<form name="form" method="post" action = "process.order.php">

<?php
while($fetch = mysql_fetch_array($order_query){

$order_id = $fetch['oid'];
$order_status = $fetch['ostat'];

?>

   <input type="checkbox" name="order_row[<?=$order_id?>]" id="1" value="1">
   <select name="status[<?=$order_id?>]" id="status[<?=$order_id?>]"
   <option value="Ordered">Ordered</option>
   <option value="Backordered">Backordered</option>
   </select>
<? } ?>


<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="submit"> </form>
```

In process.order.php:

```
<?php
if(is_array($order_row)){
foreach($order_row as $order_id=>$val){
```

...followed by the rest of the script. I tried using this: [How to implement "select all" check box in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/386281/how-to-implement-select-all-check-box-in-html)
and this:
[Select All Checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7259335/select-all-checkbox)

I'm trying to avoid using jQuery at this moment. Is there a way I can call the checkbox name generated by the PHP script into the javascript code?

**Update:**
I'd like to use a function that I can call across multiple pages. Thus, calling embedding the form name in the JS won't be practical for me. Also, I'd like it to be a checkbox - the button's worked great, but I'm trying to keep the UI simple and I already have a lot of buttons I'm trying to get rid of...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### [Working Example](http://jsbin.com/ijudav)

You can do like this:

```
var frm = document.forms['form'];
for (var i = 0, l = frm.elements.length; i < l; i++) {
   if (frm.elements[i].type === 'checkbox') {
      frm.elements[i].checked = true;
   }
}
```

Similarly, to uncheck all set:

```
frm.elements[i].checked = true;
```

to `false`.

You can also easily create `checkAll` and `unCheckAll` functions using above code.

---

By the way, an `id` with only numeric value is invalid, you should use alpha or mix of alpha and numeric characters.

Comment: In HTML5 IDs can be numeric. _The id global attribute is now allowed to have any value, as long as it is unique, is not the empty string, and does not contain space characters._

Comment: @j08691: yup i know, mentioned because question isn't tagged html5

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have to support IE6 or 7, the following will work.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/5S7QU/)**

```
var checkAll = document.getElementById("checkall");

checkAll.onclick = function(){
    [].forEach.call(
        document.forms['form'].querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox']"),
        function(el){
            el.checked=true;
    });
}
```

​
​

Comment: `querySelectorAll` doesn't work in all browsers or works in latest standard-complieant browsers only: http://caniuse.com/queryselector

Comment: I will need to support older browers unfortunately.