# How to add class to all rows

Tags: javascript, jquery

In given example, I can select/deselect each row on clicking on checkbox from td, but how to select/deselect all rows on click  `id="selectAll"` from th

**JS :**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("input[type='checkbox']").change(function (e) {
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $(this).closest('tr').addClass("warning");
        } else {
            $(this).closest('tr').removeClass("warning");
        }
    });
});
```

**[Demo Here (Fiddle)](https://fiddle.jshell.net/w9zkwb1f/)**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select All Checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7259335/select-all-checkbox)

Comment: no need to two function . try my answer @Appy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should cover all cases including switching `selectAll` appropriately  when other inputs are selected/unselected

```
   var $dataInputs;

   var $selectAll = $('#selectAll').change(function() {
       $dataInputs.prop('checked', this.checked)
                .closest('tr')
                .toggleClass("warning", this.checked);
   });


   $dataInputs = $("input[type='checkbox']").not('#selectAll').change(function(e) {
     // toggle class on this row
     $(this).closest('tr').toggleClass("warning", this.checked);

     // adjust `selectAll` based on all rows selected or not 
     $selectAll.prop('checked', function() {
       return $dataInputs.length === $dataInputs.filter(':checked').length;
     });

   });
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://fiddle.jshell.net/cvw12481/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the clicked checkbox is  `selectAll` or `not` like this `$(this).attr('id')=='selectAll'`

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("input[type='checkbox']").change(function (e) {
    
       if($(this).attr('id')=='selectAll'){
          
           if($(this).is(":checked")){
           
               $('table').find('tr').addClass("warning");
                  
             $('table').find("input[type='checkbox']").prop('checked',true);
            
            }else{
            
             $('table').find('tr').removeClass("warning");
                                   
            $('table').find("input[type='checkbox']").prop('checked',false);
            
            }
       }else{    
            
             if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
         
                $(this).closest('tr').addClass("warning");
            
             } else {
        
              $(this).closest('tr').removeClass("warning");
              
             }
             
             
             if($("input[type=checkbox]:checked").not('#selectAll').length==0){
          
                $('#selectAll').prop('checked',false);
             
       
}else if($("input[type='checkbox']:checked").not('#selectAll').length==$("input[type='checkbox']").not('#selectAll').length){
       
         $('#selectAll').prop('checked',true);
       }
       
       }
             
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover table-condensed">
    <tr>
        <th><input type="checkbox" id="selectAll"/></th>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Title</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" />
        </td>
        <td>Hello</td>
        <td>Hello</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" />
        </td>
        <td>Hello</td>
        <td>Hello</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" />
        </td>
        <td>Hello</td>
        <td>Hello</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" />
        </td>
        <td>Hello</td>
        <td>Hello</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Note this doesn't unselect `selectAll` if a selected row is unchecked when all rows previously selected

Answer (score -1):

https://fiddle.jshell.net/w9zkwb1f/5/

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
 
  $("#selectAll").click(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
      $("input[type='checkbox']").prop("checked",true);
      $("table tr").addClass("warning");
    }
    else{
      $("input[type='checkbox']").prop("checked",false);
      $("table tr").removeClass("warning");
    }
  });

    $("input[type='checkbox']").change(function (e) {
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $(this).closest('tr').addClass("warning");
        } else {
            $(this).closest('tr').removeClass("warning");
            $("#selectAll").prop("checked",false).removeClass("warning");
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover table-condensed">
    <tr>
        <th><input type="checkbox" id="selectAll"/></th>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Title</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" />
        </td>
        <td>Hello</td>
        <td>Hello</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" />
        </td>
        <td>Hello</td>
        <td>Hello</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" />
        </td>
        <td>Hello</td>
        <td>Hello</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" />
        </td>
        <td>Hello</td>
        <td>Hello</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Doesn't manage the classes for selectAll or uncheck selectAll when a row is unselected